# What influenced the fact in almost all European languages ​the word human "man" means a male?

Tags: historical-linguistics, etymology, indo-european, proto-germanic, word-formation

Why "werman" (OldEnglish man as male) became simply Man (human) and "wifman" (OldEnglish man as female) became woman?

Man in English (man, human)
Homme in French (man, human)
Mann in German (man, human)
Homo in Latin (man, human)

What in history influenced this formation of language? I know it's called androcentrism. But I would like to understand what in history formed the concept of man (human) as a man (male).  Why did these common words for both sexes, meaning “human,” narrow down to the concept of “man” (male)?

Did the Bible influence this (spread texts about the first man as a man (male) into the languages ​​that were then being formed), or did the language already exist like this before the Bible?  Or were languages ​​formed independently of the Bible?
And so it was formed simply because of wars and patriarchy?

Thank you.

Comment: German has two words, *Mensch* is the usual word for human, but *Mann* ist "man, male" only. Also, the usual classical Latin word for "man, male" was *vir*, not *homo*.

Comment: You say, “in almost all languages”, but you only really give two examples: Latin (and its descendants) and Common Germanic (and its descendants), which are close to each other geographically and were in each other’s sphere of influence. There are tons of languages where this didn’t happen, even in the same region: Celtic languages have reflexes of _*gdoni̯os_ ‘human’ (cognate with Latin _homō_) vs _u̯iros_ ‘man’; Greek has _ἄνθρωπος_ ‘human’ vs _ἀνήρ_ ‘man’. Further afield, Chinese and Japanese 人 _rén_ / _hito, -jin_ is exclusively ‘human’ (男 _nán_ / _otoko, dan-_ is ‘male’), etc.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm interested in why this narrowing and exclusion of women happened?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148738/discussion-on-question-by-orii-what-influenced-the-fact-in-almost-all-european-l); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score -2):

Proto-Indo-European **mónus* and its cognates, from which English "man" is supposedly derived, originally meant exactly male person, so there is no apparent narrowing.

The word for "human" in PIE was **dʰǵʰémōn*, from which derived the word "human", so no narrowing as well.

In Balto-Slavic "man" is **mangjás*, supposedly cognate with English "man", so in modern Russian it is "muzhchina" or (archaic) "muzh".

It seems, we can see narrowing only in some Romance languages.

Comment: I’m interested in why it turns out that the entire language is always masculine?  for example "human and HIS rights" in English.  In the Russian language, the masculine gender is accepted as generally accepted (neutral).  Studenty (all group) and Studentki (only women).  In dictionaries, words are always in the masculine gender (krasnyi (red) not krasnaya).  Feminine gender marked.  In French they are a man and a woman are Ils and not Elles, and two women are Blles.  For what reason do languages ​​develop this way?  Because of religion?

Comment: PIE _*mon-_ absolutely also means ‘human being’, not just ‘male person’, as evidenced by its reflexes as far apart as Indo-Iranian and Germanic. Whether the double meaning represents a narrowing-down or a broadening-out, and whether that process happened in the proto-language or later is anyone’s guess. At any rate, there was certainly a narrowing-down _within English_, where OE _mann_ almost exclusively meant ‘human being’; and the absence of the meaning ‘human’ in Balto-Slavic must also be a narrowing-down.

Comment: @Anixx Thank you. I’m interested to know why the masculine gender was chosen as the main gender in the language?  "human and HIS rights", "the person and HIS opinion".  always masculine when we do not know the gender of the person.  In Russian, a group of people is called by the masculine gender.  female gender marked.  Why did it happen?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet and indeed the generic sense of *man- in Germanic is retained in the German pronoun man and in Icelandic maður (the -ður in the nominative singular is the regular, albeit unintuitive reflex of an earlier -nnr obscuring its cognacy)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it is rather widening in Germanic, in PIE the root *mon- meant exclusively male (Greek amazon - manless etc)

Comment: @Orii English borrowed noun ~ *person-* as masculine gender, but Latin noun *persōna* and French noun *personne* both have feminine gender.

Comment: @Arfrever the word "person" and "human" has no gender. Why is it masculine? Why not feminine?

Comment: @Orii regarding professions, I think, it is obvious, why most of them are masculine, because women historically did only one thing: domestic work. In Russian professions have -ша suffix, which historically meant "wife of the man of that profession"

Comment: @Orii https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English#Nouns says: 「Grammatical gender survived to a limited extent in early Middle English before being replaced by natural gender in the course of the Middle English period. Grammatical gender was indicated by agreement of articles and pronouns (e.g., *þo ule*. "the feminine owl") or using the pronoun *he* to refer to masculine nouns such as *helm* ("helmet"), or phrases such as *scaft stærcne* (strong shaft), with the masculine accusative adjective ending *-ne*.」

Comment: @Orii Coincidentally, Proto-Slavic noun [\**osoba*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/osoba), Polish/Czech/Slovak [*osoba*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/osoba), Ukrainian/Russian [*особа*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/особа) also have feminine gender, regardless of biological gender of given person.

Comment: @Anixx No. The meaning ‘human’ is widely attested. The derivation of _Amazon_ from this root is far from certain, for one thing; but even if it is related to _*mon-_, it is from a **derived** form with an obscure _*-gʷi̯o-_ extension, just like the Balto-Slavic form. There is no evidence that the specific derivation _*mongʷi̯o- ~ mn̥gʷi̯o-_ meant anything but ‘male person’, but there is ample evidence that the root _*mon-_ itself also, probably primarily, meant ‘human being’ – logical if it is indeed the same root as _*men-_ ‘think, cogitate’.